# TCL command wrapping

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a TCL proc that will allow me to wrap statements and then 'execute' them internally.

For example, if I originally have :

```
set var $tmp
```

I want to have some procedure :

```
proc wrapper {command} {
   puts "do something here"
   puts $command #ie below : write "set var $tmp" to stdout
   EXECUTE COMMAND HERE
   puts "do something else here"
}

set void [wrapper {set var $tmp}]
```

My motivation is that I'm trying to write my own timing/profiler for individual statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try with `time` command which is already available with `Tcl` if your only intention is to just get the time taken by a set of code to execute.

> time script ?count?

This command will call the `Tcl` interpreter `count` times to evaluate script (or once if `count` is not specified). It will then return a string of the form

```
503.2 microseconds per iteration
```

which indicates the average amount of time required per iteration, in microseconds. Time is measured in elapsed time, not CPU time.

**Example :**

```
set code_block {
    foreach x "1 2 3" {
        set y [expr {$x*20}];
    }
}

puts [time $code_block 10]; # Executing the code for 10 times
```

which might produce random outputs such as

```
11.9 microseconds per iteration
```

**Update 1 :**

If you want to print the commands along with execution which is also possible. You can override the `time` command with `rename` command.

```
rename time _time; # Changing the 'time' to '_time'
# Defining your own 'time' command
proc time {command {count 1}} {
    # Printing the commands here
    puts $command
    # Calling the actual '_time' command
    # and returning that value from here
    return [_time $command $count]
}
```

Place the above code at the top of your code and usage of `time` command after this will be using our customized procedure only.

They are passed as set of command which in turn, yes, a string. But, while the evaluation of the code, it will behave as if like how it will work in a `tclsh`.

As answered by Mr.Peter, if your code involves accessing the previous level of commands, variables, then you have to use `uplevel` or `upvar` based on your needs.

**Reference :** [time](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/time.htm), [rename](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/rename.htm)

Comment: i was more interested in the general solution of wrapping a function and executing the statement within. this is a solution to the specific problem that motivated it, though.  if possible, i'd like to not only 'execute command here' but print out the command. i'm new to tcl, but the latter at least seems feasible. i'm passing the command as a string (i think?). executing it seems like another issue.

Comment: This is good. And if I don't want to use/rename time directly, this answer gives me enough fuel to write my own wrappers for printing the code block and then executing it. So in update 1, puts $command will print code_block?

Comment: You might also use execution traces for command execution time tracking, but they've got a lot of overhead (as they inhibit bytecode compilation).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "EXECUTE COMMAND", use

```
uplevel 1 $command
```

Note that if you attempt to time a script using a command like your `wrapper`, it won't be byte-compiled, which means that it won't perform the way it would inside a procedure.

Documentation: [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm)